# How would I make this R code more concise (using S4 class)?

Tags: r, r-s4

This code seems redundant to me, but I am unsure how I would make it more concise? I heard that I could use a likelihoodCalculator class which would be assigned SpecificLikelihoodFactorXXXX objects, but I'm not sure how I would do this.

```
 likelihood <- (density*count)/100000000
  
  if (factorA=="Yes") {                 
    likelihood<- likelihood*.35
  } 
  
  if (factorB<30){
    likelihood <- likelihood*1.31   
  }  

  if (factorC>50){
    likelihood <- likelihood*1.9 
  } else if (factorC>25){
    likelihood <- likelihood*1.6 
  } else if (factorC>10){
    likelihood <- likelihood*1.3 
  } else if (factorC==0){
    likelihood<- likelihood
  }
  
  if (factorD=="Yes"){
    likelihood <- likelihood*1.66 
  }
```

Comment: You don't need S4. Just get rid of the else statements since none of them do anything.  Many of them just assign a variable to itself and the factorC > 25 and factorC > 50 if statements can never be reached since factorC > 10 would be taken first.

Comment: Using S4 here is *"I'm a hammer, everything is a nail"* mentality. You can simplify some code here, sure, but there's nothing that an object-oriented paradigm is going to enable or make easier in this sample code. Quite the opposite, learning and debugging S4 just to improve this code will take longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option that uses the [`case_when()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) function from the [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) package.

```r
library(dplyr)

likelihood <- (density*count)/100000000

likelihood <- if_else(factorA == "Yes", likelihood * 0.35, likelihood)
likelihood <- if_else(factorB < 30, likelihood * 1.31, likelihood)

likelihood <- case_when(
  factorC > 50 ~ likelihood * 1.9, 
  factorC > 25 ~ likelihood * 1.6, 
  factorC > 10 ~ likelihood * 1.3, 
  factorC == 0 ~ likelihoodOfHarm
)

likelihood <- if_else(factorD == "Yes", likelihood * 1.66, likelihood)
```

**Note**: I interpreted this line

```
} else if (factorC==0){
    likelihoodOfHarm <- likelihoodOfHarm
}
```

to be a typo and replaced it with `likelihood <- likelihoodOfHarm`. Feel free to remove this in the `case_when()` function if this is incorrect.

And just a reminder, there's a balance in making things concise and making things difficult to modify and change.

**Edit**. Made use of `dplyr`'s [`if_else()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html) function instead of base R's `ifelse()`

Comment: If you're using `case_when`, you might as well use `if_else`, as it is safer than base R's `ifelse`.

Comment: Another way (slight code-golf, slight readability) is `likelihood * if_else(factorD == "Yes", 1.66, 1)`. It might be just a preference thing, but if it reduces how many times I have to type (long) variable names, it reduces the likelihood (yes, I typed that three times  ... my fat-fingers) that I have a typo and snag an error :-)

Comment: I got this error when I tried using `case_when`:   `Error: condition must be a logical vector, not a formula object.`  Any suggestions?

Comment: It might be because I chose factorC=1 and I don't have anything for something less than 10 but more than 0.   I think this should work:  `factorC >1 ~ likelihood * 1.1  `

Comment: @youtube that error would occur because `factorC` is a `NA` value or something other than a number. Otherwise, it should work. But yes, the `case_when()` conditions don't have anything to account for values of `factorC` that are between 0 and 10. This will return a `NA` value. So as you've pointed out, you'll want either `factorC >1 ~ likelihood * 1.1` or you can have a default value `TRUE ~ likelihood` or something similar as the last condition. I hope that helps.